# Coldfusion CFHTTP SSL no client cert

Tags: ssl, coldfusion, client-certificates

I need help figuring out if there is a way to bypass the client cert requirement using CFHTTP tag over SSL. I am getting a handshake error response using coldfusion. However using postman I'm able to bypass the certificate in the settings and the api call goes through fine.

Comment: Never heard of an option to ignore certs in CF, but you can do some TrustManager trickery with Java's HttpClient. The other option is using a 3rd party plugin like `CFX_HTTP5` which is a custom tag that can be used like `cfhttp` and allows bypassing certs. If you are struggling with TLS 1.2, you can fix that problem by upgrading to Java 8 (make CF use its JRE), available with CF10+.

Comment: Which version of CF?

Comment: Usually when I see SSL cert issues, it is related to using an old JDK that doesn't support the latest SSL TLS ciphers.  Please add your JDK and ColdFusion versions to the post.

Comment: Better to identify the cause and fix it, rather than bypassing certs, since that can pose security risks.